# User registration form throws validation errors on already unset profiles´ fields

Tags: users

Using Drupal 7 with Profile2: I have a number of profile types, with different fields, some of which I want a registrant to already fill up during the registration process. I´ve checked "Show during user account registration" for all. In my custom module, I´m first taking the registrant´s choice of profile, then unsetting (unset(); also tried hide() and ...[#access]=FALSE) all the other profiles and then rendering the registration form. This 'shows up' correctly because I only get to see the chosen profile fieldset. However, when I submit the form I get validation errors (required fields) on the unset profiles´ fields. So apparently only unsetting/hiding/etc. won´t do the trick. What am I missing?

Appreciate any help!

Best,
Mir

Comment: Have you looked at this post: [Restrict profile2 type per roles](https://www.drupal.org/node/1593230). It allows for profile2 types to be restricted per role.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module  solves the issue!

> This module enables administrators to set unique registration paths per Profile2 profile type.

Comment: thanks Krishna, was too excited, thus failing to follow post decorum :)